# InflateException after upgrade to android studio 3.0 & 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, exception

i am using [ExpandableLayout](https://github.com/traex/ExpandableLayout) library, it was working very good, but after upgrading to **gradle 3.0**, i faced this error:

`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayoutItem
...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Header`

on line:

```
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
```

and my `item.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayoutItem
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/expandableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:contentLayout="@layout/content"/>
```

Comment: Have you added `compile com.github.traex.expandablelayout:library:1.3` in your gradle dependencies?

Comment: see `Caused by:` in your stacktrace

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` and `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Header`

Comment: yes @dalla92 i did, it was working fine before upgrading to **gradle 3.0**

Comment: so what is the *full* stacktrace? add it to your question

Comment: nothing interesting, i cant add it to the question it is too long, all about `android.view.LayoutInflater`

Comment: I do not know what bothered you, there is no path to the code in the error log, sorry any way...

Comment: @Anas, I'm having the same issue as you after upgrading from 3.0 to 3.0.1,  all my packages have become unresolved but the funny thing is that gradle is building with no errors. This seems to be a bug

Answer (score 0):

Try to invalidate the cache as it may be corrupted. Goto File>Invalidate Caches/Restart

Comment: Have you updated the platform tools and sdk build tools as well?